# update python associated with pip3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I am trying to run following command on my mac:

```
pip3.7 download -q -d ./libs -r requirements.txt
```

But I am always getting the error as follows:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

But, while doing

```
  which python3.7
```

I am getting as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

As suggested in a similar post here, I tried `brew update` and `brew upgrade`, but the issue is still there.

I think, if I associate pip3.7 with `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`, I can solve this issue.

But I am not able to figure out how I update associated python with pip3.7 from `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7` to `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

**EDIT**

I have been able to update python associated with pip3.7 with help of a post as follows:

First I did `which pip3.7`, which gave: `/usr/local/bin/pip3.7`.
I then changed first line of this with the desired python path i.e. `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`. But still facing the same issue as before.

Even I have tried with following command:

```
 python -m pip download -q -d ./libs -r requirements.txt
```

Then I am getting below message:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020
```

even though while doing `which python`, I am getting `Python 3.6.5`

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall all Python installations and reinstall it by using brew? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285028

Comment: Maybe this article is helpful: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: "_I then changed first line of this with the desired python path i.e. `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`_" this is not something one should do. Not familiar with _brew_, but I believe you should instruct it to reinstall _Python_ (and _pip_) from scratch and avoiding doing such changes yourself (let _brew_ have entire control over its own files). I would also recommend against using the `pip`, `pip3.7`, etc. scripts directly and favor using `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install ...` instead, this is the surefire way of using _pip_. (Additionally maybe _pip_-install things only inside virtual environments.)

Comment: try  `python3 -m pip3 download -q -d ./libs -r requirements.txt` instead.